# How to Load vsto addin with officejs taskpane

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Currently, I am working on vsto addin migration to officejs task.
Since, complete migration not possible, looking to partially implement few functions in officejs taskpane and keep few functions as is in vsto addin ribbon.

Is there a way to load officejs taskpane when Vsto addin tab is selected from ribbon.

Please help. Thank you in advance

Tried to search in msdn forum but didn't find any article for the same

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that programmatically through the Outlook Object Model. The best you can do is simulate a click on a ribbon button that shows the pane. You can either use [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-and-microsoft-active-accessibility) or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am a its author) and its [SafeExplorer](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object for that:

```vb
'simulate a click on "Viva Insights" button
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
set Ribbon =  sExplorer.Ribbon
oldActiveTab = Ribbon.ActiveTab
Ribbon.ActiveTab = "Home"
set Control = Ribbon.Controls("Viva Insights")
Control.Execute
Ribbon.ActiveTab = oldActiveTab 'restore the active tab
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will check if i can use this workaround

Answer (score 0):

The *Office JavaScript API* (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for calling web add-ins programmatically or just launching them. As a possible workaround, if your web add-in has a ribbon button, you ,ay consider using any UI automation API or components for clicking the button programmatically, for example, see [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) for more information.

There is no trivial communication channel between VSTO/COM add-ins and Office web add-ins. The best what you could do is to suppress the web add-in (prevent it from loading) if your VSTO add-in is installed in Outlook for desktop. Here is what MS states for that:

> If you have an existing COM add-in, you can build equivalent functionality in your Office Add-in, thereby enabling your solution to run on other platforms such as Office on the web or Mac. In some cases, your Office Add-in may not be able to provide all of the functionality that's available in the corresponding COM add-in. In these situations, your COM add-in may provide a better user experience on Windows than the corresponding Office Add-in can provide.

> You can configure your Office Add-in so that when the equivalent COM add-in is already installed on a user's computer, Office on Windows runs the COM add-in instead of the Office Add-in. The COM add-in is called "equivalent" because Office will seamlessly transition between the COM add-in and the Office Add-in according to which one is installed on a user's computer.

You can read more about that in the [Make your Office Add-in compatible with an existing COM add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/make-office-add-in-compatible-with-existing-com-add-in) article.

Finally, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will check this.